# Sort the list L by the ratio of the elements in the 2-tuples in place

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting

I am trying to sort the list L by the ratio of the elements in the 2-tuples.

```
Parameters
----------
L : {list} of 2-tuples ({tuple}) of {int}

Returns
-------
None   

Example
-------
>>> L = [(2, 4), (8, 5), (1, 3), (9, 4), (3, 5)]
>>> sort_by_ratio(L)
>>> L
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (8, 5), (9, 4)]
```

So far I have

```
L[:] = sorted(L,key = lambda ratio: ratio[0]/ratio[1])
```

but it somehow gave me a list of `[(2, 4),(1, 3),(3, 5), (8, 5), (9, 4)]`

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: `/` for ints is floor division on Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [(2, 4), (8, 5), (1, 3), (9, 4), (3, 5)]
L[:] = sorted(L,key = lambda ratio: 1.*ratio[0]/ratio[1])
print L
```

Comment: `float(ratio[0])/ratio[1]`. Or better yet: `from __future__ import division`.